# Sort JSON dictionaries using datetime format not consistent

Tags: json, sorting, python-3.x, dictionary, datetime-format

I have JSON file (post responses from an API) - I need to sort the dictionaries by a certain key in order to parse the JSON file in chronological order. After studying the data, I can sort it by the date format in metadata or by the number sequences of the S5CV[0156]P0.xml

One text example that you can load in JSON here - http://pastebin.com/0NS5BiDk

I have written 2 codes to sort the list of objects by a certain key. The 1st one sorts by the 'text' of the xml. The 2nd one by [metadata][0][value].

The 1st one works, but a few of the XMLs, even if they are higher in number, actually have documents inside older than I expected.

For the 2nd code the format of date is not consistent and sometimes the value is not present at all. I am struggling to extract the datetime format in a consistent way. The second one also gives me an error, but I cannot figure out why - string indices must be integers.

```
# 1st code (it works but not ideal)

# load post response r1 in json (python 3.5)
j=r1.json() 

# iterate through dictionaries and sort by the 4 num of xml (ex. 0156)

list = []
for row in j["tree"]["children"][0]["children"]:
    list.append(row)

newlist = sorted(list, key=lambda k: k['text'][-9:])
print(newlist)


# 2nd code. I need something to make consistent datetime,
# except missing values and solve the list index error

list = []
for row in j["tree"]["children"][0]["children"]:
    list.append(row)

# extract the last 3 blocks of characters from the [metadata][0][value]
# usually are like this "7th april, 1922." and trasform in datatime format
# using dparser.parse 

def date(key):
    return dparser.parse((' '.join(key.split(' ')[-3:])),fuzzy=True)

def order(slist):
    try:
        return sorted(slist, key=lambda k: k[date(["metadata"][0]["value"])])

    except ValueError:
        return 0

print(order(list))


#update
    orig_list = j["tree"]["children"][0]["children"]


    cleaned_list = sorted((x for x in orig_list if extract_date(x) != DEFAULT_DATE),
                          key=extract_date)    


    first_date = extract_date(cleaned_list[0])
    if first_date != DEFAULT_DATE:  # valid date found?
            cleaned_list [0] ['date'] = first_date
    print(first_date)

    middle_date = extract_date(cleaned_list[len(cleaned_list)//2])
    if middle_date != DEFAULT_DATE:  # valid date found?
            cleaned_list [0] ['date'] = middle_date
    print(middle_date)

    last_date = extract_date(cleaned_list [-1])
    if last_date != DEFAULT_DATE:  # valid date found?
            cleaned_list [0] ['date'] = last_date
    print(last_date)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly you can't use the .xml filenames to sort the data if it's unreliable, so the most promising strategy seems to be what you're attempting to do in the 2nd code.

When I mentioned needing a datetime to sort the items in my comments to your other question, I literally meant something like [`datetime.date`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#date-objects) instances, not strings like `"28th july, 1933"`, which wouldn't provide the proper ordering needed since they would be compared lexicographically with one another, not numerically like `datetime.date`s.

Here's something that seems to work. It uses the `re` module to search for the date pattern in the strings that usually contain them (those with a `"name"` associated with the value `"Comprising period from"`). If there's more than one date match in the string, it uses the last one. This is then converted into a `date` instance and returned as the value to key on.

Since some of the items don't have valid date strings, a default one is substituted for sorting purposes. In the code below, a earliest valid date is used as the default—which makes all items with date problems appear at the beginning of the sorted list. Any items following them should be in the proper order.

Not sure what you should do about items lacking date information—if it isn't there, your only options are to guess a value, ignore them, or consider it an error.

```
# v3.2.1
import datetime
import json
import re

# default date when one isn't found
DEFAULT_DATE = datetime.date(1, 1, datetime.MINYEAR)  # 01/01/0001
MONTHS = ('january february march april may june july august september october'
          ' november december'.split())
# dictionary to map month names to numeric values 1-12
MONTH_TO_ORDINAL = dict( zip(MONTHS, range(1, 13)) )
DMY_DATE_REGEX = (r'(3[01]|[12][0-9]|[1-9])\s*(?:st|nd|rd|th)?\s*'
                + r'(' + '|'.join(MONTHS) + ')(?:[,.])*\s*'
                + r'([0-9]{4})')
MDY_DATE_REGEX = (r'(' + '|'.join(MONTHS) + ')\s+'
                + r'(3[01]|[12][0-9]|[1-9])\s*(?:st|nd|rd|th)?,\s*'
                + r'([0-9]{4})')
DMY_DATE = re.compile(DMY_DATE_REGEX, re.IGNORECASE)
MDY_DATE = re.compile(MDY_DATE_REGEX, re.IGNORECASE)

def extract_date(item):
    metadata0 = item["metadata"][0]  # check only first item in metadata list
    if metadata0.get("name") != "Comprising period from":
        return DEFAULT_DATE
    else:
        value = metadata0.get("value", "")
        matches = DMY_DATE.findall(value)  # try dmy pattern (most common)
        if matches:
            day, month, year = matches[-1]  # use last match if more than one
        else:
            matches = MDY_DATE.findall(value)  # try mdy pattern...
            if matches:
                month, day, year = matches[-1]  # use last match if more than one
            else:
                print('warning: date patterns not found in "{}"'.format(value))
                return DEFAULT_DATE

        # convert strings found into numerical values
        year, month, day = int(year), MONTH_TO_ORDINAL[month.lower()], int(day)
        return datetime.date(year, month, day)

# test files: 'json_sample.txt', 'india_congress.txt', 'olympic_games.txt'
with open('json_sample.txt', 'r') as f:
    j = json.load(f)

orig_list = j["tree"]["children"][0]["children"]
sorted_list = sorted(orig_list, key=extract_date)
for item in sorted_list:
    print(json.dumps(item, indent=4))
```

To answer your latest follow-on questions, you could leave out all the items in the list that don't have recognizable dates by using `extract_date()` to filter them out beforehand in a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/functional.html#generator-expressions-and-list-comprehensions) with something like this:

```
# to obtain a list containing only entries with a parsable date
cleaned_list = sorted((x for x in orig_list if extract_date(x) != DEFAULT_DATE),
                      key=extract_date)
```

Once you have a sorted list of items that all have a valid date, you can do things like the following, again reusing the `extract_date()` function:

```
# extract and display dates of items in cleaned list
print('first date: {}'.format(extract_date(cleaned_list[0])))
print('middle date: {}'.format(extract_date(cleaned_list[len(cleaned_list)//2])))
print('last date: {}'.format(extract_date(cleaned_list[-1])))
```

Calling `extract_date()` on the same item multiple times is somewhat inefficient. To avoid that you could easily add the `datetime.date` value it returns to the object on-the-fly since it's a dictionary, and then just refer to it as often as needed with very little additional overhead:

```
# add extracted datetime.date entry to a list item[i] if a valid one was found
date = extract_date(some_list[i])
if date != DEFAULT_DATE:  # valid date found?
    some_list[i]['date'] = date  # save by adding it to object
```

This effectively caches the extracted date by storing it in the item itself. Afterwards, the `datetime.date` value can simply be referenced with `some_list[i]['date']`.

As a concrete example, consider this revised example of displaying the datesof the first, middle, and last objects:

```
# display dates of items in cleaned list
print('first date: {}'.format(cleaned_list[0]['date']))
middle = len(cleaned_list)//2
print('middle date: {}'.format(cleaned_list[middle]['date']))
print('last date: {}'.format(cleaned_list[-1]['date']))
```

Comment: I receive an index error:
day, month, year = VALID_DATE.findall(value)[-1] 
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: On one post response ("india congress") it works ok http://pastebin.com/9Hdfn4YH, it moves at the beginning the ones that doesn't have any value. However for other post responses (inclusive the one I have shared above in pastebin "iraq") I receive an index error:
day, month, year = VALID_DATE.findall(value)[-1] 
IndexError: list index out of range.
[-1] suppose to match the last one, not sure why I got this error

Comment: Not sure what you meant by pastebin "iraq". Works for me on both your "json_sample" and "india congress" pastebin samples. I have added a `try/except` around the `findall()` call to have it print an error message along with the value string being parsed if an `IndexError` occurs. Hopefully the additional information can help debug the problem. The `[-1]` means the last one, but assumes there was a least one—I tried to make the `VALID_DATE` regex handle all the variations I saw in the  "json_sample" data.

Comment: "iraq" and "india congress" are 2 different post request's search keys I sent to a search engine. It back to me with 2 post responses that are the JSON structure I have upload to pastebin. All the text sentences you extracted on the other question has "iraq" in the first pastebin and the 2nd pastebin has "india congress"

Comment: I got 2 errors now:
1. I still get "list index out of range" this because some times no value is there so [-1] is out of range, I guess
2. raise IndexError('from findall() on value: "{}"'.formate(value))
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'formate'

Comment: I am loading the text in json like you so I cannot see why with you is fine. I have added a 3rd (that is not working) "olympic games" http://pastebin.com/HFzmfyYu

Comment: I misspelled `format` in my previous update and have fixed it. Sorry, didn't notice because I was never encountering the `IndexError` so that code path was never executed in my own testing. I will try your latest "olympic_games" pastebin and see what happens.

Comment: I get no error running the code with  "olympic_games". Don't know what the issue is...something must be different between our setups. I'm using Python 3.5.1 since you tagged your question python-3.x. If you put the correction I made for `format` in, you should at least be able to tell what value string is causing the problem.

Comment: Python 3.5.1 |Anaconda 4.0.0 (64-bit); Eclipse; apparently I get issue with the "-" Hyphen
IndexError: from findall() on value: "17–28 march 1980". If I run code again I get same error when the date has the Hyphen. I am in Anaconda with no problem so far. It has many libraries.

Comment: Actually that's a Unicode "en dash" character—but shouldn't be a problem for the regex in my answer (and isn't for me using plain Python 3.5.1). I can modify the code to avoid raising an `IndexError`, but if the `findall()` didn't find a match about all that can be done is return the `DEFAULT_DATE`—which really wouldn't solve the problem of a parseable date not being found.

Comment: I have installed plain Python 3.5.2 to another machine and give me the same error of Python 3.5.1 |Anaconda 4.0.0 (64-bit). On your version1: day, month, year = VALID_DATE.findall(value)[-1]  # last if multiple matches. IndexError: list index out of range. On your v.2: During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred: raise IndexError('from findall() on value: "{}"'.format(value))
IndexError: from findall() on value: "monday, 30th june—thursday, 17th july 1980".

Comment: However to load my text to json (after cleaning it a bit) I use j = json.loads(r1.text_clean) - I have notice you use json.load. If I use json.load. I got error 'str' object has no attribute 'read'. Btw we loaded differently also in the previews question and that one works great. So it's not that the problem.

Comment: I get the same results as you do using plain Python 3.5.2 (e.g. the double IndexError messages from v2) **if I purposely change the value to "GARBAGE" to force findall() to fail**. There are two messages with v2 because the `except` raises a different exception object from the one that triggered it (even though it happens to be the same type of exception). I use json.load() because it take an open file argument. json.loads() expects a string argument. That shouldn't make a difference as long as the string and the file's contents are identical. The file is one of your pastebin postings.

Comment: what you want me to try, then? Why yours works and mine not?

Comment: It's difficult if I can't reproduce your problem with the test files you've provided. **However**, I did notice a problem trying to manually use the regex in the Python console which explained by the value: "monday, 30th june—thursday, 17th july 1980" wasn't working (which isn't in any of the test files you have put on pastebin—and have modified the regex pattern to make it work. Please try my latest update, which we'll call v3, and see if it works better.

Comment: it looks promising. I am testing it with several search results and let you know

Comment: I have tested the code several times: It worked most of the time except once: data_found = datetime.date(int(year), ORDINAL_MONTHS[month], int(day)) - KeyError: 'februry' - I thought if the code finds a misspelling suppose to treat as known "warning: no date matches"

Comment: below some of "warning: no date matches" I did not understand why the code can not recognise them: "monday. 26th march—thursday, 12th april. 1984" (full stop?) - "28th june,1971–9th july,1971" (missing space?) - "13 february—24february 1989" (missing space?) - "7december—18december 1987" (missing space?) - "monday, august 9th, 1909, to friday, august 27th, 1909." (inversion month-day?)

Comment: TBH they are minor issues as they are usually 1-2% of the entire document and they are all moved at the beginning as agreed, the one that worry me is the KeyError: 'februry' as it blowup the code

Comment: The regex pattern could safely be modified to handle _some_ of these failures. Why don't you put a list of them on pastebin for me to look at? As for the misspelled month, the code currently doesn't handle that—if you knew basic Python well enough, fixing that is something you could easily do yourself (and you would have been able to determine by looking at the existing code to that it didn't already). The issue is that you're dealing with human data-entry error, and there's almost an infinite number of them possible. The best that can be done is to try to deal with the most common ones.

Comment: All the warnings I have found so far are the ones I have mentioned above. However I have pasted them here http://pastebin.com/2rXG5Lkp

Comment: As for the misspelled month I cannot really try to deal with the most common ones I would prefer something like "if KeyError: pass" and even if I lose the sentence associated with that dictionary is not a big deal as will be a small %. I am actually doing a SA of all the sentences about 500 for result

Comment: Thanks for the additional pastebin info—better than me typing them all in (avoids more potential human-error). I have already made a relatively simple modification to avoid a `KeyError` from a misspelled month name. Calling this v3.1. Modifying the regex to handle the other variations is proving to be somewhat of a challenge, partly because one of the reasons some of them are failing to match is because they are in month-day-year order instead of the usual day-month-year...

Comment: Based on the warnings you were getting I've updated my answer to v3.2 to address many, although not all, of them. The ones with misspelled month names or lacking a year will still cause warnings, but the others including those in month-day-year order should now work.

Comment: once sorted, how to extract the first, the middle and the last valid date in datetime_format? Problem is I will not know how many not valid dates it will be on front. Best way I think will be put the valid ones on a list and pick up the first, middle and last value, what do you think? I need them for a visualisation after running the SA analysis

Comment: See the latest update—mostly near the end of my answer—which attempts to answer your latest follow-on questions.

Comment: I did not get this:
date = extract_date(some_list[i])
if date != DEFAULT_DATE:  # valid date found?
    some_list[i]['date'] = date

Comment: That snippet shows how to add a valid date extracted from the list item `some_list[i]` to the (same) item and associate it the name `date`. if you did that for all the items in the list, you can later get the date value or check for its existence by simply checking `if 'date' in some_list[i]: the_date = some_list[i]['date']` which is less computationally expensive than calling `the_date = extract_date(some_list[i])` whenever you want the date info or to check whether the list item has valid date information.

Comment: I have tried your advise. however to set at the begenning the 3 dates (1st, middle, last) I have to call 3 times the extract_date anyway, is that correct?

Comment: Yes, you will need to call `extract_date()` every time you want to get the date of an item in the list. That could be avoided if you used the my final piece of advice, which was to call it once on every item but save the result back into the item. After doing that, all you would need to do is refer to value that was already extracted—as opposed to going through all the processing required to extract it again.

Comment: I have used your final piece of advice. The very first time I extract a single item I have to call the function anyway. Therefore if I have to use the item only once it is not make much difference, is that right? just to check if I got the idea.

Comment: I need an advice: my code is completed. It parses all the sentences and extracts the dates; then all the ordered sentences are passed to a sentiment module that I am importing in the code. At the end I am using a multi-processing system to run a second function that is a graph (matplotlib) to visualise the result of the sentiment. It works but, It is using all my physical RAM (8GB). I don't really want to post all my code here to ask an advice because it is part of a degree dissertation.. How I can do to get an advice in a discrete way?

Comment: I'm not sure you appreciate some of the fine points. `extract_date()` has to be called on every object to sort them and potentially again to filter-out the ones with invalid dates. If you create a `cleaned_list` as shown, that is what is happening. That could be optimized to once per object by first calling the function on each of them and storing the results. After doing that both the sorting and filtering could be done without calling it again. I don't really know if the optimization would be worth it though, since I don't know enough about everything that's going on.

Comment: Sounds like you need a computer consultant. Sorry, I don't know where you could get the kind of help you need. Maybe you can find another [StackExchange Community](http://stackexchange.com/sites#) where asking _that_ question—where to get such help—would be appropriate. I assume you're in academia, so there may be an institutional resource at yours for folks in your predicament.

Comment: I have added at the end of my question what I did' using your final advice. Once extracted I can re-call first_date, middle_date, last_date without using  extract_date() any more. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes, that was what I meant. If you're only doing it for those three objects, it's probably not worth worrying about—go ahead and call it again on them.

Comment: a quick question. for code necessity I need to define both sorted_list and cleaned_list. They both invoke extract_date and that's fine. However in the console stdout I got a repetition of  print('warning: date patterns not found in "{}"'.format(value)). there is a way to print it only once?

Comment: There's at least a couple of ways to do it. The most hacky (quick and dirty, inelegant, amateurish) would be to define a global variable that controlled whether `extract_date()` prints the warning. A better approach that avoided using a global variable would be to add a "print flag" argument to the function with a default value indicating it should print warnings, and then use `functools.partial()` to create a second version of the function which passed it the opposite of the default value for the new second argument. You could then use that version whenever you didn't want warnings printed.

Comment: Note: If you really need both `sorted_list` and `cleaned_list`, you easily create the latter from the former without calling `extract_date()` again. Both lists are sorted and the only difference between them is there may be objects at beginning of the first for which `DEFAULT_DATE` was returned (and a warning printed). If you went through the `orig_list` once at the beginning and _unconditionally_ added the result of calling `extract_date()` to the items. You could then use it to both sort and determine the `cleaned_list` elements without calling it again.